# SLDS via Node.js

Tags: lightning-design-system, slds, node.js

I am trying to work with the Lightning Design System in a Node.js program and I have a question about the design tokens. What is the best way of either dynamically changing the design token values, OR, changing them and regenerating the static CSS files.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: I want to change some of the design token values to just another value for a simple HelloWorld vue.js page I am testing out